# Make: wildcard работает через раз

Tags: компиляция, makefile, clang++, gnumake

Есть простенький Makefile
В папке только 3 файла *exp.h exp.cpp main.cpp*

1) Ввел команду "make" в первый раз

Такая вот ошибка:

```
g++    -o EXECUTABLE.work   
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

2) Ввел команду "make" во второй раз(без make clean)

```
g++   ./obj-all/exp.o ./obj-all/main.o -o EXECUTABLE.work
```

Все хорошо собралось.

Почему ето происходит?
Я подозреваю, что make не может на ходу найти файлы в только что созданной папке obj-all.
Но, все же, у нас последовательное выполнение.

Версия Make:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Код:

```
CC=g++ 

DIRS:=obj-main obj-exp  
MAIN_OBJ=obj-all

.PHONY: all
.PHONY: clean

all:  exp.o main.o
        mkdir -p obj-all   # mkdir -p would not brake makefile if folder exist
        for dir in $(DIRS); do \
                cd $$dir; \
                cp *.o ./../obj-all; \
                cd -; \
        done
        $(CC) $(wildcard ./obj-all/*.o) -o EXECUTABLE.work #работает через раз
#       $(CC) $(MAIN_OBJ)/*.o  -o EXECUTABLE.work  #работает всегда
main.o:
        mkdir -p obj-main
        $(CC) main.cpp -c
        mv *.o obj-main/
exp.o:
        mkdir -p obj-exp
        $(CC) -c exp.cpp
        mv *.o obj-exp/
clean:
        rm -f *.o
        rm -rf obj-*
        rm -f *.work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. синтаксис [правила](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html):

   ```
   цели : пререквизиты
       рецепт
   ```
2. функции программой *gnu/make* вычисляются **до** начала выполнения рецепта
3. `$(wildcard ...)` — это функция

отсюда вывод: так как при первом запуске функция была вычислена **до** начала выполнения рецепта, она вернула пустую строку (не было файлов, соответствующих шаблону). а при втором запуске файлы уже были, и функция вернула их имена.

рекомендация: создавайте файлы **до** выполнения рецепта, в котором вам надо будет получить их список с помощью функции *wildcard*.

---

иллюстрация:

```
правило:
    mkdir -p каталог
    touch каталог/файл
    echo $(wildcard каталог/*)
```

рецепт, начинающийся с `echo`, выведет пустую строку. хотя к этому моменту `каталог/файл` уже будет существовать.

```
правило: каталог
    echo $(wildcard каталог/*)

каталог:
    mkdir -p $@
    touch $@/файл
```

сначала выполнится правило `каталог`, в котором он будет создан, а в нём создан `файл`. а уже затем выполнится рецепт, начинающийся с `echo`, и будет выведено имя `каталог/файл`